# Selenium Webdriver (Python): How to set Page Object for a "send.key" line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

New to selenium here. I am trying to optimize this line of code into a Page Object file. This is the actual script to type "USA" in the search field box:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']").send_keys("USA")
```

The way I am doing it keeps giving me an error so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong (see below):

**Actual Test Case file:**

```
from pageObjects.Confirm_page import ConfirmPage

class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_endtoend2(self):
        confirmPage = ConfirmPage(self.driver)

   
    confirmPage.getCountryName().send_keys("USA")
```

**Page Object file**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class ConfirmPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    typeCountry = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='country']")

    def getCountryName(self):
        self.driver.find_elements(*ConfirmPage.typeCountry)
```

**The error message:**

```
>       confirmPage.getCountryName().send_keys("USA")
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from getCountryName() so you get none as return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the error says nonetype doesn't have send_keys , because getcountryname() returns nothing , you should return something there and also use find_element instead of elements**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class ConfirmPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    typeCountry = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='country']")

    def getCountryName(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*ConfirmPage.typeCountry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having a link to the website it's hard to say for sure, but it looks like your indentation is wrong in your test.  Shouldn't your send keys command be within the function?

```
from pageObjects.Confirm_page import ConfirmPage

class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_endtoend2(self):
        confirmPage = ConfirmPage(self.driver)

   
    confirmPage.getCountryName().send_keys("USA") #this needs to tab over so it's within the function call
```